# CMakeLists.txt structure

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I wanted to start a cmake project and I have many files. The structure is the following.

`types.h` is included in `functions.h` and in `dag.h`

`functions.h` is included in `basic.cpp, br.cpp, IR.cpp` and `UIR.cpp`

`functions.h` and `dag.h` are included in `dag.cpp, dag-cmp.cpp, dag-cover.cpp, dag-make.cpp` and `dag-sum.cpp`

Obviously I have also in the same directory a `main.cpp` which includes `types.h, dag.h` and `functions.h`

Which is the best solution for a CMakeLists.txt and for the cmake project?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is *the best* solution, but I'd prefer the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(myproject)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    basic.cpp
    br.cpp
    IR.cpp
    UIR.cpp
    dag.cpp
    dag-cmp.cpp
    dag-cover.cpp
    dag-make.cpp
    dag-sum.cpp
    main.cpp
)

set(HEADER_FILES
    types.h
    functions.h
    dag.h
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_14)
```

- Using the variable `${PROJECT_NAME}` makes it easy to change the project's name, because you have to change it only once.
- Including all header and source files allows an IDE to know that those files belong to the project.
- Setting a target's properties should be preferred over changing CMake variables. Therefore, I encourage to use `target_compile_features` instead of `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(myproject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(myproject all.cpp all.h)
```

1. This can be a possible format. Enter space separated .cpp and .h
   files. If a cpp/.h file contains space then write it in double
   quotes.
2. You can edit C++ Standard as per you.
3. This is a very basic setup,
   feel free to add stuff as per your requirements.

Comment: don't i need to any add_library for any of the source files?

Comment: Depends ! Do you need to build libraries ?

Comment: for now i wanted to run this main.cpp using cmake. But this main.cpp uses functions and structures declared inside the sources.cpp i mentioned (are those sources libraries for my main.cpp?). A second step is to link the project to an external library.

Comment: I don't think so. Try compiling it after just adding all cpps to the add_executable . It shd work. Also don't forget to accept this as an answer !

Comment: I downloaded a library and built it using cmake. It's called Hypro. How can i link that library to one of my external cmake project?

Answer (score -1):

Consider that all your files are in a src/ folder. CMake can list them automatically :

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE source_files src/*)
add_executable(exec ${source_files})
```

The first line will look for all files in the src folder (and its subfolders) and store the list in source_files var. 
The second line will load files from source_files var and add them to the executable 'exec'

Comment: GLOB_RECURSE is a bad solution. CMake doesn't know when to rerun cmake, so new files are ignored. If you can use CMake 3.12, it's more okay if you use the CONFIGURE_DEPENDS option: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/file.html#glob-recurse

Comment: True, I didn't think about that. Using GLOB_RECURSE, we have to rerun CMake everytime we modify the file tree.